# no audio help please

Tags: audio

I recently installed elementary OS on a toshiba chromebook 2 using this guide:
https://github.com/brendenyule/NativeToshibaCB2Guide/wiki

Everything works great except for the sound. I hear nothing. I have tried what seems like every guide to troubleshoot this and still can not get it to make a sound. I have installed drivers and gotten it to display a dummy output, which is working as it is correct with the sound my computer should be making. No sound though.

important information:
At the end of the guide it has you install drivers i assume to get the touchpad working. It feels like a similar issue but i there are none on the guide for audio.

sudo apt-get update has these fails, which seem rather important for my audio problem:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
(It wont let me post more hyperlinks for some reason so )

W: Failed to fetch   404  Not Found(another audio.dev thing)

W: Failed to fetch   404  Not Found(elementary update binary 64 stuff)

W: Failed to fetch   404  Not Found(elementary update binary i386 stuff)
```

Also alsamixer
alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

alsa
Usage: /sbin/alsa {unload|reload|force-unload|force-reload|suspend|resume}

alsa reload etc. did not work. Ive been at this trying to fix it all kinds of ways, including many clean usb boot installs for well over 10 hours in the past two days. Please let me know what i need to do or try to get this  audio working on this beautiful machine.

Comment: Please provide total links, If not possible, keep a * or give some gap =)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/pulse-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```